# Lethargy: Short Versus Long Sessions

Tags: meditation

I have roused myself to meditate, but I am experiencing lethargy and drowsiness throughout the whole session, drowsiness which doesn't cause me to sleep but which I perceive helplessly. My question is should I:

a) continue to merely watch my hazy thought process as long as I am not sleeping

b) reduce the length of my sessions so that the *time* spent in meditation is devoid of drowsiness.

I've done a session of 30 min, and am wondering whether to reduce it to 15 or 20 min.

Thank you.

Comment: If you give in to laziness, it is reinforced. That said, don't push yourself just because a rule says so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a 30 minute session, my recommendation is to continue to merely watch the hazy thought process (as long as there is not sleeping). Hopefully, after a while, the haziness will clear, like dawn fog clears eventually as the sun rises.

Answer (score 1):

Lethargy and drowsiness are classical hindrances to achieving upacara samadhi. You might try meditating at a different time of day or try exercise. Or you may try meditating outside in nature or a park. A classical approach is to meditate overlooking a vast landscape. You might try coffee or dextrose. I heard of one person who would meditate sitting on top of a kitchen table (the fear of falling off kept him awake!!). Meditating with a group or friend may help. Or you might try a walking meditation. A fitness program my put your body into a higher energy state.